# ModuleNotFoundError when it actually is in the path

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I've tried adding it directly to path through control panel ('c:\projects\parser'), and also appending it before I try my import. It works with the childs folder, not the parents.

```
.
└── parser
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── utils
            ├── __init__.py
            └── rebuild_parsers.py
```

This is what I've tried.

```
C:\>python
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('c:\\projects\\parser')
>>> from tests.utils.rebuild_parsers import build_lexer_parser
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.utils'

>>> sys.path.append('c:\\projects\\parser\\tests')
>>> from utils.rebuild_parsers import build_lexer_parser
```

I don't really understand why is it not working. Both folders (tests and utils) have an `__init__.py` file

Of course if I run it from the parser folder, it works, I just want to understand why it doesn't get it as a module.

```
C:\Projects\parser>python
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tests.utils.rebuild_parsers import build_lexer_parser
>>>
```

Comment: Which directory are you running it from? Does that directory also contain `tests/`?

Comment: I was running from C:, it doesn't contain tests, but once i add it to path it works as a module, contrary to parser.

Comment: Do you somehow have the [`tests`](https://pypi.org/project/tests/) package installed? Try `pip uninstall tests`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same tree structure you gave. It seems to have worked for me.

Using Mac and python3.8.7.

Here's the tree:

```
% tree parser
parser
└── tests
    ├── __init.py__
    └── utils
        ├── __init.py__
        └── rebuild_parsers.py
```

This is what my rebuild_parsers.py contains:

```
# rebuild_parsers.py
def exmaple():
        print("Hello")
```

Here's the code I wrote in the terminal:

```
>>> import os, sys
>>> sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "parser"))
>>> from tests.utils.rebuild_parsers import exmaple
>>> example()
```

It seems to have worked. Can you check it out.

Comment: Hi it doesn't work. Where are you in the terminal? I think `os.getcwd()` requires me to be in the parent of parser. I still tried there and fails. I don't think it could be the python version, as the import for utils does work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in Windows OS. In addition to possible level injection as a parent, the problem with sys.path.append is that it creates a windows path which Python is not searching for some reason despite it being added to the sys.path. Instead try to use

```
ROOT_PATH = 'c:\\projects\\parser\\tests'

sys.path.append(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, ''))
```

It will add file's grandparent to sys.path in a proper way.